# C можно ли с Денвера  отсылать сообщения на почту ?

Tags: php

C localhost можно отсылать сообщения на почту? то у меня не получается, этот код выводит "messege acepted for delivery". ошибки не какой не выдает, но сообщение не приходит.

```
 if (mail("зкшьук@gmail.com", "the subject", "Example message",   
    "From: bondarvadim95@gmail.com \r\n")) { 
      echo "messege acepted for delivery"; 
  } else { 
     echo "some error happen"; 
  }
```

Отсылаю вот так

```
  mail("зкшьук@mail.ru", "the subject", 'авыавы', 
 "From: webmaster@example.com \r\n" 
."X-Mailer: PHP/" . phpversion());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нельзя, если не настроен почтовый сервер(настроен?). 
Denwer "присылает" в специальную папочку

```
\tmp\!sendmail
```

UPD:
С Денвера нельзя, в нем стоит заглушка. 
UPD2: 
для извращенцев: можно, если эту заглушку переписать. Но это очень непросто.

Comment: На денвере отсылал почту: ставил какой-то монитор (нагуглил по запросу "отправка почты в денвере"), он слушал ту самую временную папочку и при появлении в ней сообщений отсылал их.

Ничего переписывать т.е. не надо, все уже сделано. Единственное - надо было иметь учетную запись на одном из почтовых серверов. 

Соответственно спамом не займешься, рассылки не отправишь и учетку лучше новую создать - на всякий случай))

Хотя опять же - для рассылки лучше использовать уже готовые решения (хотя бы PHPList, а не стандартный mail).